# Is it normal to not be able to console.log a variable assigned to a fetched API?

Tags: javascript, variables, fetch, console.log

I'm trying to fetch an API and it's working but for the problem that my variable GOT will not console.log.  If I write it into the web dev tools I can see the object in the console but I can't console log it from my editor.  This is probably not a great question. I'm relatively new to the game.  thanks!

```js
let url = "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters";

let GOT;

fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((response) => {
    GOT = response;
    console.log(GOT);
    return GOT;
  });

console.log(GOT);
```

Comment: Completely normal.  You're writing asynchronous logic.  `GOT` does not exist at the time that you try to log it.  The web request has not finished yet.

Comment: `console.log(GOT);` will happen before `then`'s callback (where `GOT` gets assigned a value) gets executed.

Comment: oh ok, I get it.  thanks for the quick response from both of you!